# Why use gems for serving assets instead of the vendor file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am relatively new to Rails and I have a question about serving assets from a gem vs just loading the files into the asset pipeline.

As far as I can tell, they do virtually the same thing in that they both make the files available in the asset pipeline to be called in the manifest.

What are the advantages to serving something like

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

as a gem instead of just putting

```
/vendor/assets/javascripts/jQuery.js
```

in the vendor assets and loading it that way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The advantage is you don't have to add the file(s) to your repo and manage updates, you update the gem and you've updated the dependency.  They can also add helpers to use the assets more easily.

Not all JS/CSS projects are out-of-the-box compatible with the asset pipeline too, so sometimes the gems will do that work for you as well.

Just because the files get served to clients doesn't make it much different than any other dependency in your application.

Answer (score 1):

The gem includes the unobtrusive javascript for Rails as well as jQuery itself. It also allows you to user `assert_select_jquery` in tests.

Answer (score 0):

Benefits:

1. You don't need to manually copy them when you get a new version of 
   jquery released, gem will make sure to add the latest codes only.
2. Check this link: 
    https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails/blob/master/lib/jquery/assert_select.rb#LC48 
    It provides couple of methods which helps while testing your code.

Comment: https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails/blob/master/lib/jquery/assert_select.rb#LC48

Answer (score 0):

jquery-rails is gem contains js file for both jquery.js, jquery_ujs.js. If you does not include jquery-rails, then you have include both jquery.js and jquery_ujs.js.If you are not using gem for jquery-rails, you have manually keep track what version jquery.js is used for jquery_ujs.js. Currently these dependency management is taken care by gem 'jquery-rails'.