# What's the point of using bootstrap-sass vs including bootstrap files directly in the asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I don't get the added value of using bootstrap-sass vs just including Bootstrap js and css files in asset pipeline ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/27930763/429758

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why use gems for serving assets instead of the vendor file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27930674/why-use-gems-for-serving-assets-instead-of-the-vendor-file)